# Whats wrong with my partition table?

Tags: linux, partition, usb, fdisk

I'm a bit lost here.
I got my trusty old external 500Gb  USB drive but it refuse to mount:

I think my partition table is invalid:

### sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sdb

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4e5041f4

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1           16065   976768064   488376000    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5           16128   976768064   488375968+   7  HPFS/NTFS
```

### sudo sfdisk /dev/sdb

```
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
OK

Disk /dev/sdb: 60801 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Old situation:
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1          1   60800   60800  488376000    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sdb5          1+  60800   60800- 488375968+   7  HPFS/NTFS
Input in the following format; absent fields get a default value.
<start> <size> <type [E,S,L,X,hex]> <bootable [-,*]> <c,h,s> <c,h,s>
Usually you only need to specify <start> and <size> (and perhaps <type>).
```

### Lastly dmesg

```
[ 1014.245138] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291457
[ 1235.310900] exe (4284): /proc/4284/oom_adj is deprecated, please use     /proc/4284/oom_score_adj instead.
[ 1843.019531] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1843.020509]  sdb: sdb1 < sdb5 >
[ 1846.615552] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[ 1846.615560] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1846.615565] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1846.615572] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1846.615579] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 60 3f 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1846.615591] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6307584
[ 1846.615598] quiet_error: 6 callbacks suppressed
[ 1846.615602] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291456
[ 1846.615609] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291457
[ 1846.615613] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291458
[ 1846.615617] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291459
[ 1846.615621] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291460
[ 1846.615625] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291461
[ 1846.615629] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291462
[ 1846.615633] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291463
[ 1849.831315] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[ 1849.831323] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1849.831331] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 1849.831340] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[ 1849.831349] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 60 3f 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1849.831367] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6307584
[ 1849.831375] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291456
[ 1849.831384] Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291457
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the drive is now throwing some errors, the DMESG output shows it pretty well. Those logical blocks look to be within the defined partitions, but it does seem to be enough for the OS to not want to mount the device. At this point, I'd throw `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` at it and see what it yields. That should deliver the SMART information for the drive and should show if it really is throwing bad clusters.

Comment: sudo smartctl -a -i -d scsi /dev/sdb
    smartctl 5.40 2010-07-12 r3124 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local    build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen,     http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

    Device: WDC WD50 00BEVT-22ZAT0    Version:     
    Device type: disk
    Local Time is: Wed Aug 10 21:59:34 2011 SAST
    Device supports SMART and is Enabled
    Temperature Warning Disabled or Not Supported
    SMART Health Status: OK

    Error Counter logging not supported
    Device does not support Self Test logging

Comment: @Henrike That's going to make diagnosing the problem a lot harder.

Comment: lol why ? Sorry I tried to format it better but when i press enter it submits :S

Comment: @Henrike The fact that the device doesn't support SMART error-value reporting will make this hard to fully diagnose (I could see your original formatting, since I have superpowers). The log-entries `Buffer I/O error on device sdb5, logical block 6291456` are the ones that suggest some bad blocks on the hard-drive. Without SMART-capability, it's hard to be certain.